# String from plist file in NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk

I'm new in iPhone SDK. Now i'm working with plist file witch content strings. How can I set a value of the first element in the file with type 'plist' to `NSString` variable? I have plist content in `NSArray`:

```
NSString *countriesList = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Countries" ofType:@"plist"];
countries = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:countriesList];
```

Comment: Are you trying to pull the first member of the 'countries' array (in which case you'd use [countries objectAtIndex:0])? How is your 'countries' variable defined?

Comment: No, I want something like that  NSString * countryName =[[NSString alloc] setText:[countries objectAtIndex:1]]; . But it didn't work.

'countries' defined as NSArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *countryName = [countries objectAtIndex:0];
```